# Second Isomorphism Theorem Notation Query

Tags: group-theory

I'm reading about the Second Isomorphism Theorem and it seems to me as if $HN/N$ should equal $H/N$. Because, $hnN$ is the same as $hN$. I just don't understand what's wrong with my train of thought, as surely if I were correct, the book wouldn't be using the notation $HN/N$.

I hope this doesn't sound like a silly question, it's really doing my head in.
Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 4):

In the usual framework $H$ and $N$ are subgroups of a larger group $G$.
It is usual to assume only that $H$ is a subgroup and $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.
In particular, $N$ may not be a subgroup of $H$ (let alone normal), so $H/N$ doesn't make sense in all cases.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that $N$ may not even be a subset of $H$, let alone a subgroup, so you take $HN$ which is a subgroup of $G$ (as $N$ is normal) and then $N$ is normal in $HN$ so the quotient is well defined.

Comment: A small detail: If $N$ is a subset of $H$, then it is a subgroup, because they are both subgroups of the same group. But you are right, both normality and being a subgroup in the first place are not included in the assumptions.

Comment: You're right of course, and to me this is what provides the intuition behind the actual theorem; you make $N$ a subset by intersecting with $H$ and quotienting $H$ by that or you make $H$ large enough to contain $N$ by taking the product $HN$ then quotienting by $N$. The intuition is about how you can make $H/N$ actually make sense.