# Second Isomorphism Theorem for groups Notation Query

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

The Second Isomorphism Theorem states :
If G is a group, N⊴G and H≤G, we know that:

N∩H⊴H and H/(N∩H)≅HN/N.

and it seems to me as if HN/N should equal H/N. Because, hnN is the same as hN. I just don't understand what's wrong with my train of thought, as surely if I were correct, the book wouldn't be using the notation HN/N.

I hope this doesn't sound like a silly question, it's really doing my head in. Thanks for the help guys!

I dont understand the answer given to the original post which I've copied above
which is

"In the usual framework H and N are subgroups of a larger group G. It is usual to assume only that H is a subgroup and N is a normal subgroup of G. In particular, N may not be a subgroup of H (let alone normal), so H/N doesn't make sense in all cases."

my problem with this answer is I cant understand why doesn't H/N make sense if N isn't a subgroup of H,
since N is a normal subgroup of G and H is a subgroup of G then for every g in G there exists gng^{-1} ∈ N , which entails hnh^{-1} ∈ N  which makes N "normal" to H, such that for each coset hN = Nh and thus the operator of multiplying cosets of hN is closed, and for each hN there exists h^{-1}N such that

hN * h^{-1}N = N

which makes it so that every elemnt of H/N has an inverse,
so why doesnt it make sense to look at H/N as a quotient group ?

So just to reiterate my two questions are:
1.
If G is a group, N⊴G and H≤G, the 2nd theroem of isomorphism says:
N∩H⊴H and H/(N∩H)≅HN/N.
why isnt HN/N rewritten as H/N

2. If G is a group, N⊴G and H≤G and H doesnt contain N. Why is H/N not a quotient group ?

thanks

Cay (https://math.stackexchange.com/users/250263/cay), Second Isomorphism Theorem Notation Query, URL (version: 2015-07-08): [Second Isomorphism Theorem Notation Query](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1353736)

Comment: It is true that $HN/N$ and what you call $H/N$ are the same thing. But the notation $H/N$ is only used when $N$ is a subgroup of $H$. Since this is not always the case, we write $HN/N$. ($N$ is clearly a subgroup of $HN$). Thing is, the definition of a quotient group requires $N$ to be a normal subgroup of the original group. So we can't call $H/N$ a quotient group if $N$ is not contained in $H$.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Every element of $HN/N$ has a representative of the form $hN$. But the notation for quotients is restricted to the case where the "denominator" is a normal subgroup of the "numerator". As $HN$ is the smallest subgroup of $G$ that contains both $H$ and $N$, that is the "correct" "numerator."

Comment: I like to think of this Isomorphism Theorem as the counterpart of the Fourth/Lattice isomorphism theorem. That lattice isomorphism theorem tells you how the subgroups of $G$ that contain $N$ correspond to subgroups of $G/N$. This theorem tells you how that subgroups of $G$ that do *not* contain $N$ correspond to subgroups of $G/N$, or how they behave under the canonical projection.